# Как переустановить Debian Linux с сохранением данных?

Tags: debian, linux

У меня уже год стоит дебиан. Несколько месяцев назад я зачем-то подключил unstable репозиторий. С последующими обновениями начало всё периодически глючить слетать. Апач упал. Надоело плясать с бубном вокруг родного ноута. Решил переставить систему с нуля, хотя для линукса, как мне кажется, это не мосем целесообразно. Мне нужно сохранить каталог /home  и /home2 с правами доступа. Там все мои фото и видео. Но это не сложно, потому что это физически другой раздел на харде. То есть я просто этому разделу укажу нужную точку монтирования. Важнее другая проблема: останется ли после всего этого у меня история скайпа и пиджина. Да и вообще в домашнем каталоге хранится много всяких настроек программ. Что будет с этими настройками? Они тоже обнулятся или останутся старые?
Расскажите. Может кто уже так делал? Не обязательно в дебиане, я думаю этот прцесс во всех дистрибутивах похож. Расскажите подробнее.

Comment: См. также вопрос о поиске изменений в системных настройках http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/542212/130

Answer (score 3):

Ничего не обнуляется. Все ваши настройки, по идее находятся в /home/myuser, если вы конечно не извращенец. Настройки приложений находятся в /etc/. То что у вас отдельный раздел с /home/ это конечно хорошо, но когда вы установите новую систему, и смонтируете туда /home/, с правами будет не все так гладко, потому что uid  и gid пользователя скорее всего будут отличатся, но вам никто не помешает сделать chown -R. А то, что находится в /etc/ советую переносить по мере надобности, так как понимаю что там с точки зрения конфигурации не все хорошо. А так в целом процесс достаточно тривиален.

Comment: Ну так в том-то и дело, что в домашней директории могут находится "битые" конфиги. Можно их будет обнулить? А вот история скайпа на весь золота...

Comment: И ещё.. Я же могу запомнить uid&gid и потом присвоить их юзеру в новой системе? И как это сделать, если возможно, конечно...

Comment: Конфиги вы сможете удалить, т.е. двигаться методом исключения, "не работает удалить". UID GID вы можете посмотреть в файле /etc/passwd.

Comment: > И ещё.. Я же могу запомнить uid&gid и потом присвоить их юзеру в новой системе?Да, добавить группу и пользователя с соответствующими UID и GID можно так:    # groupadd --gid 1001 mygroup    # useradd --gid 1001 --uid 1001 myuser