# Получить архив всех изменённых конфигурационных файлов системы

Tags: linux, debian

Устанавливаемые пакеты могут содержать конфигурационные файлы, обычно устанавливаемые в `/etc/`. При обновлении пакетов если такие файлы изменены, система их не переписывает, а спрашивает пользователя. Список файлов и их исходных md5-сумм хранится в БД dpkg.
Его можно получить, правда не очень красивый:

```
dpkg-query --showformat='${Conffiles}\n' --show \*
```

Как получить список всех **изменённых** конфигурационных файлов, чтобы потом записать их в архив?
Может быть есть какая-то готовая утилита?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

можно воспользоваться программой *debsums* из одноимённого пакета:

```
$ sudo debsums -ce > список-изменённых-файлов 2> список-отсутствующих-файлов
```

- `-с` — сообщить только об изменённых файлах
- `-e` — сообщить только о конфигурационных файлах
- `sudo` — т.е., административные полномочия, требуются ввиду того, что некоторые файлы могут быть недоступны для чтения рядовым пользователям

в `список-изменённых-файлов` попадут строки вида:

```
/etc/apache2/mods-available/php5.conf
```

в `список-отсутствующих-файлов` попадут строки вида:

```
debsums: missing file /etc/udev/hdparm.rules (from hdparm package)
```

---

а вообще следить за изменениями в конфигурационных файлах довольно неплохо получается с помощью программы *etckeeper* из одноимённого пакета.